# Concentration Result on Singular Values of iid Random Matrix with Nonzero Mean

Tags: random-matrices

For a random matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{N\times n}$ with iid entries, with mean zero, variance $\mathbb{E}[a_{11}^2]$, and bounded fourth moment, I know that when $N$ and $n$ are sufficiently large, the extreme eigenvalues of $A^TA$ concentrate around the following values
\begin{align}
\lambda_{\max}(A^TA)&\simeq(\sqrt{N}+\sqrt{n})^2 \mathbb{E}[a_{11}^2] ,\\
\lambda_{\min}(A^TA)&\simeq(\sqrt{N}-\sqrt{n})^2 \mathbb{E}[a_{11}^2] ,
\end{align}

which is a quite classic result.

Is there any variation of this result known for the case when the mean is not zero (but still iid, so all entries with the same mean) ?